# Getting 415 unsupported media type while consuming an api which I created

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sam", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"text/plain", "application/*"})
public void test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody Test test) {
    try {System.out.println("*******************inside**************************");
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class Test {

private String desc;
private int id;
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Request body I used is

```
{
    "id": 88,
    "desc":"test"
}
```

Even though I have added consumes in request mapping I'm getting 415 when I try to access from postman and also I have set the request header in postman, content-type as application/json

Comment: tried like this?

https://photos.app.goo.gl/kVMolL7scY3I4u0w1

Comment: Yes, I tried just like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the json converter library, so when I added jackson-databind maven dependency in my pom.xml it worked.